# Excel .Find throws an exception when it doesnt find a specific variable. How Do I stop it from breaking execution VB.net

Tags: .net, excel, vb.net

Good morning/afternoon all,

I am currently creating a program to automate a couple of excel sheets.

While this may be trivial to some. I have no clue how to stop .find throwing an exception when it doesnt find the result it is looking for.

The .find function works as intended if it can find what it is after.

```
AreaFindRow = ExportExcelWs.Range(AreaFind).Find(AreaArray).Row
```

system.nullreferenceexception

Error message: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

I have tried:

```
Try
    AreaFindRow = ExportExcelWs.Range(AreaFind).Find(AreaArray).Row
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Cannot find this value in the worksheet")
End Try
```

This however, still does not work.

Any suggestions will be tested!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume it works as in VBA - it returns a Range if it succeeds, or Nothing if it fails. The error is due to trying to use the Row property on Nothing, so you should test the Find result before you try and access any of its properties.

Comment: I have just tried it with .value to see if it will return a blank/null value and it still errors out.

Comment: Again: you should test the Find result before you try and access **any** of its properties

Comment: I am really sorry about this but I am not sure what you mean by testing it before I search for it.

Comment: Assign Find to a range variable (or whatever is vb.net equivalent) and then check if that is Nothing.

Comment: Try adding null conditionals `AreaFindRow = ExportExcelWs?.Range(AreaFind)?.Find(AreaArray)?.Row`, `If AreaFindRow IsNot Nothing Then...`

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions. It has been a huge help to my sleep deprived brain!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
If Not ExportExcelWs.Range(AreaFind).Find(AreaArray) Is Nothing Then
   AreaFindRow = ExportExcelWs.Range(AreaFind).Find(AreaArray).Row
Else
   AreaFindRow = 0
End if
```

You can then handle your code depending on whether AreaFindRow is 0 or >0

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions. John DaPleaser of Wimmin im not sure why i didnt think of this before but this is what i ended up using and it works a treat. thank you for pointing out the obvious to me!!!